# what am I doing wrong with my code in prototype?

Tags: c++

I tried to pass my prototype menu for the principal function, but says  that I haven't that variable scope. I already tried with different ways to do it,but it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void menu(int opccion); 
void agregar();
void consultar();
void eliminar();

void menu(opccion){
    do{
        switch(opccion){
            case 1:
                cout << "menu 2" << endl;
                break;

            case 2:
                cout << "menu 3" << endl;
                break;

            case 3: 
                cout << "menu 24" << endl;
                break;

            default: 
                cout << "opccion invalida" << endl;
        }
    }while(opccion != 4);
}

int main(){
    int opccion;
    string Menu[] = {"agregar","consultar","eliminar"}; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        cout << i+1 << endl << Menu[i];
    }
    cout << "what would you do? " << endl;
    cin >> opccion;
    menu(opccion);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void menu(opccion) { ... }` This doesn't look right. Is it the same in your prototype?

Comment: void menu(int opccion);  << this is my prototype

Comment: In the definition of `menu`  a type must be given for the parameter `void menu(int opccion){...`

Comment: i have the prototype like void menu(int opccion); and my function i have void menu(opccion){..};

Comment: @AaronEnriqueMorenoImperial Both the prototype and the function need to have `int` in them.  Try changing the function like Michel Billaud said, and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void menu(int opccion);
void agregar();
void consultar();
void eliminar();

int menu(){
    static const string Menu[] = {"agregar","consultar","eliminar"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        cout << i+1 << " : " << Menu[i] << endl;
    }
    int opccion;
    do {
        cout << "what would you do? " << endl;
        cin >> opccion;
        switch(opccion){
            case 1:
                cout << "menu 2" << endl;
                break;

            case 2:
                cout << "menu 3" << endl;
                break;

            case 3:
                cout << "menu 24" << endl;
                break;

            default:
                cout << "opccion invalida" << endl;
        }
    } while (opccion <1 || opccion >= 4);
    return opccion;
}

int main(){
    int opccion = menu();
    return 0;
}
```